# Image not loaded in jquery mobile image popup

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, popup

When I call from anchor tag it's working;

```
var surl = "http://192.168.1.233";
$("#imgLink").html("<a href='"+ surl + "/leave/" + filename + "'>" + filename + "</a>");
```

But when I call from jquery mobile image popup, it's not working anymore;

```
$("#imgLink").html("<a href='#popupPhoto' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-role='button' data-inline='true' data-transition='fade'>"+
                                            filename + "</a>"+
                                            "<div data-role='popup' id='popupPhoto' data-overlay-theme='a' data-theme='d' data-corners='false'>"+
                    "<a href='#' data-rel='back' data-role='button' data-theme='a' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-right'>Close</a>"+
                    "<img class='popphoto' src='"+ surl + "/leave/" + filename +"' style='width:150px; height:150px;'></div>");
```

I can see popup frame but instead of image, it shows question mark.

Answer (score 0):

Popup markup goes outside of content but still within the page.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hM4Jr/)**

Build the link button markup and the popup markup in 2 separate variables. Append the link to the container (#imgLink) and append the popup to the page. Finally trigger refresh on the page.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function(){
    var filename = "http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports";

    var markup = '<a href="#popupPhoto" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="fade">' + filename + '</a>';

    var popup = '<div data-role="popup" id="popupPhoto" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="d" data-corners="false"><a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a><img class="popphoto" src="' + filename + '" style="width:150px; height:150px;"></div>';

    $("#imgLink").empty().append(markup);
    $("#page1").append(popup).trigger('create');
});
```